# Transpose of fermion bilinears

Tags: conventions, fermions, spinors, majorana-fermions, grassmann-numbers

TL;DR

When we take the transpose of two Grassmann-valued spinors (fermions), should we add a minus sign because we end up anticommutating the two spinors?

---

More details.

I'm studying the behavior of 1+1-dimensional Majorana fermion. I use the same representation for the gamma matrices as in *Lectures on string theory* by Lüst and Theisen, chapter 7 appendix B. That is

$$\gamma^0 = i \sigma^2 \qquad \gamma^1 = \sigma^1 \qquad C= \gamma^0 \qquad \eta^{\mu\nu}=diag(-1,+1)$$

Equation B.3 of these lectures says that Majorana fermions obey the following indentity:

$$ \bar{\psi}_1 \gamma^{\alpha_1} \gamma^{\alpha_2} ... \gamma^{\alpha_n} \psi_2 = (-1)^n \bar{\psi}_2 \gamma^{\alpha_n} ... \gamma^{\alpha_2} \gamma^{\alpha_1} \psi_1.$$

However I cannot prove this identity, I always get the wrong sign on the RHS, even for simple cases such as $n=0,1$ or $2$. For instance for $n=1$, knowing that Majorana fermions are real and therefore $\bar{\psi} = \psi^\dagger \gamma^0 = \psi^T \gamma^0$, we can write the LHS as:

$$\psi_1^T \gamma^0 \gamma^\alpha \psi_2.$$

This is just a number, so it should be equal to its transpose. When we take the transpose, $\gamma^0$ takes a minus sign. If $\gamma^\alpha=\gamma^0$ then this one also takes a minus sign which cancels the first one and we get no overall sign. If $\gamma^\alpha=\gamma^1$ then the 2nd minus sign comes when we anticommute the two matrices. In every case I get:

$$ \bar{\psi}_1 \gamma^{\alpha} \psi_2 =  \psi_1^T \gamma^0 \gamma^\alpha \psi_2 = \psi_2^T \gamma^0 \gamma^\alpha \psi_1 = \bar{\psi}_2 \gamma^{\alpha} \psi_1,$$

even though the identity above says there should be a minus sign. My guess is that when I took the transpose of the LHS, I should have added a minus sign since I inverted two Grassmann-valued spinors in the process, otherwise I don't know what I did wrong.

On a related note, if the sign changes when we swap to spinors, does that imply that the trace of a fermion bilinear is no longer cyclic?

$$\text{Tr}\ \bar{\psi}\psi \neq \text{Tr}\ \psi \bar{\psi} ?$$

---

[Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/149500/) but the answer is unclear. [This post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/388079/) is actually pretty much the same question, but then why this "transpose antisymmetry" only rarely mentioned? Does it only hold for Majorana fermions?

Comment: I used ^T for the transpose everywhere. The only place I used Tr is when I was actually talking about the trace, to ask if the antisymmetry of spinors had any effect on the trace of fermionic operators.

Comment: Lord... any QFT book would have said, instead, in mainstream notation, $\bar \psi \chi =\bar \chi \psi$ ....

Answer (score 8):

In short, yes there's an extra minus sign when we reorder the terms. I've just encountered this myself and I found going very slowly helps to understand where the minus sign comes in. Let's use index notation - for some anticommuting $\psi$ (column) and $\bar{\psi}$ (row), and some matrix $M$, consider
$$\begin{align}
\bar{\psi} M \psi &= \bar{\psi}_i M_{ij} \psi_j\\
&= \bar{\psi}_i \psi_j M_{ij} &&\text{rearranging terms}\\
&= -\psi_j \bar{\psi}_i M_{ij} &&\text{anticommuting } \bar{\psi}, \psi \tag{!}\\
&= -\psi_i \bar{\psi}_j M_{ji} &&\text{relabelling } i \leftrightarrow j\\
&= - \psi_i M_{ji} \bar{\psi}_j &&\text{another rearrangment}\\
&= - \psi_i (M^T)_{ij} \bar{\psi}_j &&\text{definition of transpose}\\
&= -\psi^T M^T \bar{\psi}^T &&`\text{row $\times$ matrix $\times$ column'}
\end{align}$$
which reproduces the usual 'transposes in inverse order' but with an extra minus sign because of the anticommuting nature of the $\bar \psi$ and $\psi$ at $(!)$.

When it comes to something being equal to its own transpose, that's still correct - however, we don't have the usual 'transpose of a product' formula and instead we get extra minus signs, e.g.
$$\bar{\psi} \psi = (\bar \psi \psi)^T = -\psi^T \bar{\psi}^T$$

Comment: I have some questions about your answer: in the step (!) you use the anticommutation of bar fields with fields, but that is only true if $i \neq j$. Otherwise, you have an extra term with a Dirac delta. The other question is that I don't see very clear that you can write $\bar{\psi}\psi = (\bar{\psi}\psi)^T$ since $\bar{\psi}\psi$ is an operator after all, not a number and the transpose of an operator is not, in general, equal to the operator. I think your reasoning is good if only if $M_{ii} = 0$, as the gamma matrices are, and therefore your last equation does not hold anymore

Comment: We're taking $\psi$ and $\bar{\psi}$ as vectors of Grassmann variables. This means that $\bar{\psi} \psi$ is a 1x1 matrix, so it is trivially equal to its transpose. Grassmann variables always satisfy $\psi_i \psi_j = -\psi_j \psi_i$ even when $i = j$ since $\psi_i^2 = 0$. Obviously with fields one has to account for operators, but that isn't what we're doing here.