# What is the complex conjugate of two fermionic fields coupled? $(\bar{\psi} \chi)^{\ast} =$ ____?

Tags: fermions, spinors, complex-numbers, dirac-matrices, grassmann-numbers

Suppose $\psi$ and $\chi$ are fermionic fields, and suppose I want to calculate the hermitian conjugate of the operator $\bar{\psi} \chi$
$$
h.c.\ \mathrm{of}\ \bar{\psi} \chi = (\bar{\psi} \chi)^{\ast}
$$
I recently asked [a question here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/532758/) which states that fermion components anti-commute (since they are Grassman-valued). This leads me to calculate 
$$
(\bar{\psi} \chi)^{\ast} = (\psi^{\dagger} \gamma^0 \chi)^{\ast} = (\psi_{a}^{\ast} \gamma^0_{ab} \chi_{b})^{\ast} = \psi_{a} \gamma^{0\ast}_{ab} \chi_{b}^{\ast} =! - \chi_{b}^{\ast} \gamma^{0\ast}_{ab} \psi_{a} = - \chi^{\dagger} \gamma^{0\dagger} \psi = - \bar{\chi}\psi
$$
where I have used $\gamma^{0\dagger} =\gamma^0$, and also I've used the anti-commutation of fermion components where the "!" is. This seems to suggest that
$$
\bar{\psi} \chi + h.c.= \bar{\psi} \chi - \bar{\chi} \psi
$$
which doesn't seem correct to me, because swapping $\chi \to e_{R}$ and $\psi \to e_{L}$ I know should yield $\bar{e}_{R}e_{L} + h.c. = \bar{e}_{R}e_{L} + \bar{e}_{L}e_{R}$ (see equation (56) of this document, [of this document](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.1786), for example).

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/695933/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
(\psi_{a}^{\ast} \gamma^0_{ab} \chi_{b})^{\ast} = \psi_{a} \gamma^{0\ast}_{ab} \chi_{b}^{\ast}
$$
is not correct. Rather
$$
(\psi_{a}^{\ast} \gamma^0_{ab} \chi_{b})^{\ast} =\chi_{b}^{\ast} \gamma^{0\ast}_{ab} \psi_{a}= - \psi_{a} \gamma^{0\ast}_{ab} \chi_{b}^{\ast}
$$ 
Note that the Hermitian is defined as
$$
(AB)^\dagger = B^\dagger A^\dagger
$$
Note that there is no minus sign even if both $A$ and $B$ are Grassmann-valued.

See related post [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/529496/is-fermion-mass-imaginary-instead-of-real).

Comment: Okay from your link I'm concluding that for Grassman-valued objects we have $(AB)^{\dagger} =B^{\dagger}A^{\dagger}$ and $(AB)^{T} = - B^{T} A^{T}$. Is there a simple explanation why the difference? The link https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/388079/ has an explanation for $(AB)^{T} =-B^T A^T$, but why would this same procedure not end up in $(AB)^\dagger = -B^{\dagger}A^{\dagger}$? (I am having trouble following the logic of your provided link)

Comment: @Greg.Paul, I am with you. The difference seems ad hoc and arbitrary to me too! But most mainstream physicists seem to be OK with it.