# Sign of pair of Dirac spinor bilinear

Tags: conventions, dirac-equation, complex-numbers, dirac-matrices, grassmann-numbers

I don't understand the following statement: Any pair of Dirac spinors verifies $(\bar{\Psi}_1\Psi_2)^\dagger=\bar{\Psi}_2\Psi_1$ and it is valid for both commuting and anti-commuting (Grassmann-valued) components.

In the case of Grassmanian number, shouldn't I add an extra sign when I flip them? Is there anything else to take into account in the case of Majorana spinors?

Comment: There is no minus sign even if $\Psi_1$ and $\Psi_2$ are Grassmann-valued. See related topic here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/529496/

Comment: And see another related question here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/532934/

Comment: Surely the Dirac mass term is $m(\psi^\dagger_L \psi_R+ \psi_R^\dagger \psi_L)$? No $\gamma_0$'s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As opertors on Hilbert space, and with hermitian $\gamma_0$, we have
$$
(\bar \Psi_1 \Psi_2)^\dagger= (\Psi^\dagger_{1,\alpha}(\gamma_0)_{\alpha\beta} \Psi_{2,\beta})^\dagger\\
= \Psi_{2\beta}^\dagger  (\gamma_0)^*_{\alpha\beta}\Psi_{1,\alpha}\\
= \Psi_{2\beta}^\dagger  (\gamma_0)_{\beta\alpha}\Psi_{1,\alpha}\\
=\bar \Psi_2\Psi_1.
$$
For the Grassmann "c-numbers" we define the dagger operation to coincide with this one.